# DATE query is not incluse for To date in JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

This is my JPQL query.

```
"SELECT inc FROM MessageDtl inc WHERE inc.createdTime >= :dateFrom AND inc.createdTime <= :dateTo "
```

where dateTo=03/27/2017 & dateFrom=03/29/2017

In response, this will fetch all the records 0n 03/27/2017 & 03/28/2017. Even though I had given <= condition, records on 03/29/2017 is not fetched.

There can be a work around to dateTo plusOne day. Would like to know how can I fix without using plus one, what is the reason for this behavior ?

Comment: and do those input dates have a TIME component? or the ones in the datastore?

Comment: No time component only date

Comment: so present the schema for that table, and the SQL invoked